# Getting Objects from a file and show it in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, file, serialization, android-recyclerview

I want to show my data (objects) which are stored in a file in a RecyclerView without storing it in a list before.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch data from that file to a dataset that can be an Array or List then populate that dataset to Recycler view.

Comment: Thank you.
So, it couldn't be without using a list? I'm just asking because my file possibly contain 1000 objects and I thought this might be intensive on the memory to handle them all.

Comment: if you don't want to use list then use can use your own data structure, 1k data will not cause any performance issue. The performance concerned places should be how/when you read the data from the file. you should fetch the data from file in a convenient time that you can also use it later for optimization. Don't read file too frequently, just try to maintain efficient manner by your requirment.